# SQL Query to generate activity from stored table data

Tags: mysql, dynamic-sql, listactivity

I have three tables for storing activity related data as below.

```
Table: activity

+----+---------------+---------+
| id | activity_text | user_id |
+----+---------------+---------+
|  1 | added         |       1 |
|  2 | added         |       1 |
+----+---------------+---------+
```

```
Table: activity_modules

     +----+-------------+
     | id | module_name |
     +----+-------------+
     |  1 | posts       |
     |  2 | comments    |
     |  3 | users       |
     +----+-------------+
```

```
Table: activity_module_objects
+----+-------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
| id | activity_id | module_id | display_text | object_id |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|  1 |           1 |         1 | new post     |        10 |
|  2 |           2 |         1 | new comment  |        11 |
|  3 |           2 |         2 | on post      |        10 |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

Here activity table represents user and activity. user_id is foreign key from users table.
And object_id in activity_module_objects represents activity target like a post with id 10. It means that some action has happened on post 10.

I need output like this, Whenever I query using an user_id, lets say user_id=1, {user: {id: 1, name: 'Anil'}}

Anil added new post

Anil added new comment on post

In each activity, 'Anil', 'Comment', 'Post' will have links.

Anil liked AnotherUser's Video Wild-life

In this activity, Anil, AnotherUser, Wild-life will have links. So, using user_id I need to get user details, using module_id & object_id I need to get object details. Like if module is 'VIDEO', I need to get video_id (object_id from activity_module_objects table) data from `videos` table. If it is some other thing like, event, I need to get event_id details from `events` table.

Comment: Now that you described your entire requirements, please formulate your exact question.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it will give you user details with related object_id and module name.

```
SELECT u.*,
       amo.object_id,
       am.module_name
FROM USER u
LEFT JOIN activity a ON a.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN activity_modules_object amo ON a.id = amo.activity_id
INNER JOIN activity_modules am ON am.id = amo.module_id
```